why small graph cost more time in graphX
In this post: is-there-a-one-pass-spark-graphx-algo-to-separate-a-graph-into-small-groups, I thought that later iteration should cost less time since the graph in the later iteration should have less edges and less vertices,  however, but in my test, it's opposite, later iteration cost more time.
The related code to profile the time of each iteration is as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable



spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[4]")
    .getOrCreate()
)

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

ids = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([ (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ]).map(lambda item : Row(item))
schema =  StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False)])

vertices = spark.createDataFrame(ids, schema)
import graphframes as gf

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, 2, "similar"),
  (2, 3, "similar"),
  (3, 1, "similar"),
  (4, 3, "similar"),
  (4, 1, "similar"),
  (4, 6, "similar"),
  (6, 4, "similar"),
  (2, 5, "similar"),
  (2, 7, "similar"),
  (7, 2, "similar"),
  (8, 9, "similar")
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])

g = gf.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType,ArrayType
schema_1 = StructType([StructField("index", IntegerType(), True), StructField("seed", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("similar", StringType(), True),StructField("Time(sec)", StringType(), True)])

import time
groups = spark.createDataFrame([],schema=schema_1)
out_degree_df = g.outDegrees
i  = 1
prev_graph = g
while out_degree_df.isEmpty() == False:
    time_per_step = []
    tic_1 = time.time()
    max_out_degree_ptn=out_degree_df.agg(F.max_by("id", "outDegree")).head()[0]
    tac_1 = time.time()
    time_per_step.append(tac_1-tic_1)

    tic_2 = time.time()
    dst_column=prev_graph.edges.filter("src = %d" % max_out_degree_ptn).select("dst")
    dst_list=[row[0] for row in dst_column.collect()]
    similar_str = ",".join(str(i) for i in dst_list)

    dst_list.insert(0, max_out_degree_ptn)
    remove_id_list=dst_list
    tac_2 = time.time()
    time_per_step.append(tac_2-tic_2)

    tic_3 = time.time()
    condition=(prev_graph.vertices.id.isin(remove_id_list) == False)
    tac_3 = time.time()
    time_per_step.append(tac_3-tic_3)

    tic_4 = time.time()
    cur_graph=prev_graph.filterVertices(condition)
    out_degree_df=cur_graph.outDegrees
    prev_graph=cur_graph

    tac_4 = time.time()
    time_per_step.append(tac_4-tic_4)

    total_time = tac_4 - tic_1
    str_time = "+".join(str(round(i, 3)) for i in time_per_step)
    str_time = str(round(total_time, 3)) + "=" + str_time

    group = spark.createDataFrame([(i, max_out_degree_ptn, similar_str, str_time),], schema=schema_1)
    groups = groups.union(group)

    i=i+1

groups.show(truncate=False)

The output is as:



index
seed
similar
Time(sec)




1
4
3,1,6
1.0=0.686+0.214+0.013+0.088


2
2
5,7
2.119=1.101+0.934+0.011+0.072


3
8
9
3.649=1.884+1.712+0.006+0.047



Iteration 3 cost 3.649 seconds and most of the time is on agg and filter method and these time is much larger than that of the previous iterations.
I am confused that graph in iteration 3 is much smaller than that in iteration 1, but the cost time on  agg and filter  is much more, can someone show some light to me about this?

update
related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432752/tuning-while-loops-in-pyspark-persisting-or-caching-dataframes-in-a-loop

just found add some cache to the variable in while loop can speed the example above, but for large graph(1000+ nodes), it become even slower with cache added.
